# Adding a view with a view controller as a subview of another view controller. Doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to essentially re-implement the UISplitViewController (because it has its limits), but when I create a UIViewController viewController, and then do an "[viewController.view addSubview contentViewController.view]" on it, to add a view that already has a view controller, that content view doesn't seem to get initialised by its view controller. I guess its view controller is getting detached or deallocated, is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your code?

```
UIViewController* myController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myView" bundle:nil];
myViewClass* cellView = (myViewClass*)cellController.view;
[self addSubview:cellView];
```

The above code will add a subview using the view in the "myView" nib.

Ensure that in the nib file - 
The view is of myViewClass
the File's Owner is UIViewController and 
its view outlet is connected to the view.

Comment: Dont you mean myController there on the second line and not cellController?